# Why is Google Cloud Tasks so slow?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I use Google Cloud Tasks with AppEngine to process tasks, but the tasks wait about 2-3 minutes in the queue before being sent to my App Engine endpoint.

There is no "delay" set on the tasks, and I expect them to be sent right away.

So the question is: Is Cloud Tasks slow?

As you can see is the following screenshot, Cloud Tasks gives an ETA of about 3 mins:

[image]

Comment: cloud tasks is only slow for us if we keep sending 5xx back to it and it backs off, otherwise, the max rate is critical to reach the max concurrent (acceleration vs. velocity sort of thing).  maximum rate is how fast you ramp up to max concurrent and if too slow, it is possible to never reach max concurrent.

Comment: 4 years later still same problems unreliable for any serious use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official word from Google is that this is the best you can expect from their task queues.

In my experience, how you configure tasks seems to influence how quickly they get executed.

It seems that:

- If you don't change the default behavior of your task queues (e.g., maximum concurrent, etc.) and if you don't specify an execution time of a task (e.g., eta) then your tasks will execute very soon after submission.
- If you mess with either of these two things, then Google takes longer to execute your tasks.  My guess is that it is the extra overhead of controlling task rate and execution.

Comment: Thank you for the details, I will try to play with the settings and see if I can tune that delay!

Answer (score 0):

I see from your screenshot that you have a task with an ETA of 2 min 49 sec which is the time until your task will be run. You have *high* bucket size and concurrency numbers, so I think your issue has more to do with the parameters you are using when queueing your tasks, especially the `scheduled_time` attribute. Check your code to see if you are adding a delay to your tasks, and make sure to tune it down.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding here, that as of February 2023, I can queue tasks and then consume them VERY fast using the Python 3.7 libraries.

Takes me about 13.5 seconds to queue up 1000 tasks.
Takes about 1 minute to process those 1000 tasks using a Cloud Run deployed python/flask app. (No other processing done, just receive and reply with 200).

So, super fast!

BTW, pubsub was much slower in my tests... about 40ms per message to queue a message.

Answer (score 0):

When using Cloud Tasks with GAE, it's also relevant to mention GAE configuration.

I've faced the same issue, even found a bug created for that in the Google Bug Tracker [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135471809?pli=1)

In my case the problem was with the configuration of the GAE, to be exact with the Automatic Scalling functionality.

When there was a lot of Tasks in the Cloud Tasks Queue, GAE decided to create another instance for that, and that was the problem. Because of my GAE configuration, it took a good couple of minutes for that second instance to run, that's why some Tasks were *hanging* in the Queue.

GAE configuration is very specific to what the GAE is used for, but in my case I cranked up the resources (cpu and memory_gb) and decided to go with Manual Scalling with one instance.