# Cloud Task connection is very slow in GCP Sydney region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am running Go 1.12 App Engine in GCP to push tasks to Cloud Task. The same code runs in the US central region takes less about 50ms to push the task to the queue. However, in the Sydney region, the code takes about 1 second to push the task to Cloud Task queue in the Sydney region.

I have 2 US region deployments, both are very fast, and 2 AU region deployments, both are very slow on pushing tasks to Cloud Task.

Any idea why the performance in Sydney region is so bad?

Comment: Hey, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57544460/15774177

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. That's a different problem. The problem I experienced is the connection delay to create the task from AppEngine. Google Support said that's due to the infrastructure in the Sydney region and nothing they can do about it.